# Install Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: sql-server, odbc, pyodbc, ubuntu-18.04

The goal is to install Microsoft Driver for SQL Server on Ubuntu 18.04 to write scripts using python package pyodbc.
I make steps according [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017). The problem is when I run command `sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install msodbcsql17` then I recieve next error message:

**Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 msodbcsql17 : Depends: unixodbc (>= 2.3.1) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.**

Only relevant discussion of this problem is [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/issues/847). But I have already tried all recomendations:

1. Remove all relevant packages
2. Use clean system
3. Build unixodbc manually

Nothing helped me. Does anyone met same problem or have guide how to install this driver on clean Ubuntu 18.04 server system?

Comment: Take look here https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/issues/287 The suggestion is to use `sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install msodbcsql unixodbc-dev gcc g++ build-essential`

Comment: What happens if you try `sudo apt install python3-pip unixodbc-dev`

Comment: @GordThompson  in this case everything installs successfully moreover I can also install pyodbc and use it but to connect to MSSQL I need that specific driver.

Comment: @twoleggedhorse  thank you for the link but it is for 16 version of Ubuntu and uses other packages. I have already tried to install this packages as well but face absolutely the same problem as described above.

Comment: Now that you have unixodbc-dev installed, what does `dpkg -l | grep unixodbc` show you? On my 18.04 test VM I see `... unixodbc-dev:amd64   2.3.4-1.1ubuntu3 ...`.

Comment: @GordThompson  yes, I have exactly the same result as you. But after that `sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install msodbcsql17` returns me the save error **msodbcsql17 : Depends: unixodbc (>= 2.3.1) but it is not installable**. Have you successfully installed that driver on 18.04?

Comment: "Have you successfully installed that driver on 18.04?" - Yes, many times. Both 18.04 Desktop and 18.04 Server, but always immediately after a clean install of Ubuntu. It sounds like your `apt` setup is broken; perhaps some of the suggestions [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/223237/323236) (or the other linked questions therein) might help.